# xor: N things with variable probabilities

Tags: javascript, math

Forgive me; I'm a coder and not a mathematician, so I'm asking this to my own stack. I'm trying to reduce an array of probabilities (0-1), let's say `[.1,.3,.5]` to find:

1. The likelihood of all of them happening (simple multiplication, let's call this function `AND`: `probs.reduce((m,p)=>p*m,1)`),

   1.1 This can be written [image: x_1 :\cap: x_2 :... \cap: x_n]
2. any one of them happening (one minus none of them happening `1 - probs.reduce((m,p)=>m*(1-p),1)`, call it `OR`), and

   2.1 This can be written [image: x_1 :\cup: x_2 :... \cup: x_n]
3. `XOR` ONLY one, no more and no less, of them happening. At first I thought this was simple because if there are only two inputs, the chance of only one happening should be `OR` minus `AND`. But as I'm banging my head on this as an array of more than two values, normal XOR logic seems to disintegrate.

   3.1 This can be written (verbosely) [image: (x_1 :\cup: \neg x_2 :... \cup: \neg x_n) :\cap: (\neg x_1 :\cup: x_2 :... \cup: \neg x_n) :...: \cap (\neg x_1 :\cup: \neg x_2 :... \cup: x_n)]

Do I need to get the "OR" and then subtractively multiply *all possible AND scenarios iteratively?* Or is there a non-iterative formula to find out the total probability of exactly one probability in a list longer than two?

`0,0,0` should be 0 in my case. `0,.4.0` should yield a .4 of only one happening. `1,.4,0` should yield 0.6. I know that `.5,.5` should yield 0.25 chance of only one happening. But I'm really not sure how to calculate the chance of only one `.5,.5,.5` without counting on my fingers. My mind is saying I have to loop through each probability, and subtract from it the chance of any others (`OR` the rest of the array), then `OR` the final results... but this is speculative. That seems very weird and inefficient. I can't believe this would be an NP-Hard problem, but it's a corner of things I'm not familiar with...

Please answer in visual, logical or programmatic terms, not pure Math if possible...

** Edit here: I don't need to clarify the exact probability of a *particular* element in the array being exclusive to the others; I'm trying to find the general probability of any of them being exclusive. **

** Edit. This is what I've got now. I'm excluding all other possibilities for each individual one. Is this the fastest way?... *

```
function And(probs) {
        return (probs.reduce((m,p)=>p*m,1));
    }
    function Or(probs) {
        return (1 - probs.reduce((m,p)=>m*(1-p),1));
    }
    function Xor(probs) {
        let _exclusiveProbabilities = [];
        for (let k=0; k < probs.length; k++) {
            let _others = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < probs.length; j++) {
                if (j != k) {
                    _others.push(probs[j]);
                    console.log(k,'pushed',probs[j]);
                }
            }
            const _anyOtherProb = Or(_others);
            _exclusiveProbabilities.push(probs[k] * (1 - _anyOtherProb));
        }
        return (Or(_exclusiveProbabilities)); 
    }
```

** edit. Nope, that's great for two but doesn't work for three. **

Comment: YES - thank you. Editing the above. My brain is getting fried.

Comment: This is really more suited to math.stackexchange.com, I think, but anyway, the way to solve problems like this is to express the logical operation in terms of conjunction and negation and then apply the basic rules for that. A formula for XOR is derived in my dissertation (http://riso.sourceforge.net/docs/dodier-dissertation.pdf) in Section C.3.11. The formula probably exists elsewhere but anyway I know it's there. I think you want Eq. C.25.

Comment: Ah, this is brilliant but I don't know how to read the notation. Pr(S1 ⊕S2 ⊕···⊕Sm) = Pr(Sm)+Pr(S1 ⊕···⊕Sm−1)(1−2Pr(Sm))(C.24) ...does "m" imply you have to iterate over the series?

Comment: Right, you can iterate from p0 = 0 to pm =  Pr(S1 ⊕S2 ⊕···⊕Sm) via C.25 where m is the number of terms. Looks like S in my notation = x in your notation. P(Sk) = k'th element of your array p (indexing from 1). NOTE: An important assumption which I didn't mention before is that S1, ..., Sm are all independent. If they are not independent, a result can still probably be worked out, but it will depend on what's known about the various Sk depend on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have three probabilities, which we'll call A, B, and C.

The probability of A being the only event that happened is A * (1-B) * (1-C).  In other words, in this scenario A happened, but B did not happen and C did not happen.

But, of course it is possible that B was the only successful event, or that C was the successful event.  We will need to sum together the probabilities of all of these situations.

So, we are going to need to loop through all of the events, and compute the probability that only that event happened (and all the others failed), and then compute the sum.

For the case of three events, this would be:
`( A * (1-B) * (1-C) )  +  ( (1-A) * B * (1-C) )  +  ( (1-A) * (1-B) * C )`

If there are N total events, then there will be a total of N^2 (N squared) total terms in this expression.

Comment: Thank you. This is a really concise explanation. So one question... adding raw probability values and then squaring the number of variables is very.... counterintuitive. Not what I would have guessed. Why? I was trying to find all the XOR values one by one and then get their total OR, but that isn't working.

Comment: @joshstrike is your original goal to find the probability of "or", and you are looking at "xor" as a way to get there?

Comment: Thank you. This is what I ended up implementing. Seems like a forehead-slapper, but I somehow thought there had to be a way without iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of each event happening is the same, say `p`, and there are `n` events, and they are all independent, then there is a nice closed form solution for XOR of all the events, which is a polynomial of degree `n`.

```
sum_k=1^n (-1)^(k-1) * C(n, k) * k * P^k * (1-P)^(n-k)
```

Here:

- `(-1)^(k-1)` alternates the sign based on the number of events (k),  which reflects that for XOR to be true, an odd number of the inputs need to be true
- `C(n, k)` is the binomial coefficient "n choose k", and accounts for all ways to choose `k` events out of `n`
- `k * P^k` is the probability of `k` events occurring,
- `(1-P)^(n-k)` is the probability of the remaining events not occurring.